# Querying Different Wordpress pages depending on href value of clicked link

Tags: php, wordpress, dynamic, modal-dialog

I have a list of links on a page, each linking to an id of a div on the page. The idea is that on click, a modal launches with the inline content.

The HTML is as follows:

```
<a href="#cardiacModal">Cardiac Care</a>
<a href="#emergencyModal">Emergency</a>
.... and many more
```

and the modals:

```
<div style="display:none">
    <div id="cardiacModal">
        <?php query_posts( array('p' => 57, 'post_type' => 'directions') );
        if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
              <p><?php the_title(); ?></p>
        <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
    </div>

    <div id="emergencyModal">
        <?php query_posts( array('p' => 54, 'post_type' => 'directions') );
        if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
              <p><?php the_title(); ?></p>
        <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
    </div>
    ... and many more
</div>
```

In total, there are about 50 different links triggering 50 seperate modals. Within each modal I am using php to pull content from a specific Wordpress page. Now, this page is starting to get a bit heavy weight with over 800 lines of code!

I am looking for a different approach - to have one single modal with conditional statements saying, if the user clicked on link *x*, then we want to query page id *x* within wordpress.

Im really not sure the best way to go about this, or if it is even possible. I am basically looking for an alternate solution to avoid having 50 modals - I would rather have one modal with logic that controls which wordpress page content is being pulled from.

CURRENTLY, I think the best solution would be to place each modal in a separate php file and using jquery to load that ajax...but I would prefer an alternate solution. Thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can receive everything in the same page, like "http://domain.com/clinic?c=cardiacModal" so, in your page you put a switch statement like:

```
<?php
switch($_GET['c']){
   case 'cardiacModal' : $p = 57; break;
   case 'emergencyModal' : $p = 54; break;
   "..."
   default;
}
if(!empty($_GET['c']): ?>
 <div id="cardiacModal">
  <?php query_posts( array('p' => $p, 'post_type' => 'directions') );
    if (have_posts()) : 
        while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
          the_title();
        <?php endwhile; 
    endif; ?>
  </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Yes, exactly what I was hoping for. Let me test this out, will be back shortly.

Comment: But, why you dont use WP 'pages'? You can use the permalink '%category%/%postname%' and use a page template to do this... and list in a loop all the pages link to build a menu.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a super barebones page template for the modal boxes content pages (basically just the container for the content the bare minimum css needed) and then pipe it into the modal as an iframe or with AJAX.